# How to find what slows down Vim?

Tags: performance

In some occasions, Vim respond is very slow. Is there a procedure to easily identify what causes the problem?

Comment: Have you installed any plugins?

Comment: Something akin to `bash -x` to see what gets executed would be useful.

Comment: @Melon: Yes I only have 1 plugin installed.
muru: Can you explain further?

Comment: Oh, I don't have an answer. I was just noting that something similar to `bash -x` would be handy. `bash -x` prints out every command executed, so if you have slow loading times, you could see which commands slow it down.

Comment: Dangit, I answered a duplicate. While I vote to close this as a duplicate, I also respond to your comment: LatexBox shouldn't be called 2000 times after deleting 2 words. Now that you've  found the problem, you have to finagle with the plugin. I wish I knew more about LatexBox to help you.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes, [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/191/205) is very close to what I had in mind for this question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Vim has a built-in profile set of commands. See `:h profile`.

You would open up vim, and then run the following

```
:profile start profile.log
```

This sets up the file `profile.log` to be the log file. If it already exists, it will be overwritten. We now need to tell vim what to profile

```
:profile func *
:profile file *
```

This says to profile all functions and all script files. Overkill, perhaps. Now, you should do things that make vim act slowly. They are being profiled in the background. Once you have concluded, end the profiling.

```
:profile pause
```

And quit vim. Now, read the `profile.log` file and see what's slow. Note that this is for slow running inside of vim. If vim is slow to start up (a different problem), you should start vim with

```
vim --startuptime log.txt
```

and read the times, see what's taking so long.

Comment: I followed your instructions. After starting profiling, I used `dw` twice and then exit. Then looking at the log I got `FUNCTION LatexBox_FoldLevel(), Called 1930 times`

Comment: When I try this I get "E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version"

Comment: @BarryMcNamara You can see more about this in `:h profile`. Using profile requires vim to be compiled with `+profile`, which happens to be true for many (but not all) vim binaries provided on distributions. You might try compiling your own vim, or installing a more featurefull binary.

Comment: I'm using the default Mac one, and it seems that I have the normal version whereas profile is only included in the huge version. However, I managed to fix the closing lag I was experiencing by renaming my .vimrc to something else and then renaming it back.