# How do I enable profile in vim?

Tags: installing

I learned about [using `:profile` here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/189/1111), so I just tried to install vim with profiling enabled.

I tried this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/username --with-features=profile
```

But in the output from configure I got the message

```
Sorry, profile is not supported
```

Does that mean that profile is not an option for me at all because of my OS, or is there something that I can do to make it "supported"?

Comment: Perhaps Vim can't find `libperl.so` and skips it because of that? You should post at least the full output of `vim --version` (has linker command) and preferable also the full output of `./configure` and `make`... You should have something like `-L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl` in there.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You're right. That is missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks. I didn't think to look in the middle of the configure output before your comment. I updated the question to focus on getting `profile` enabled (a necessity for me) and `perl` is more of a want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can enable the *profile* feature via `./configure`; you either have to define `FEAT_PROFILE` or simply build a *huge* version of Vim, which then includes that feature. From `src/feature.h`:

```
/*
* +profile      Profiling for functions and scripts.
*/
#if defined(FEAT_HUGE) \
        && defined(FEAT_EVAL) \
        && ((defined(HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY) && defined(HAVE_SYS_TIME_H)) \
                || defined(WIN3264))
# define FEAT_PROFILE
#endif
```

#### TL;DR

```
./configure --with-features=huge
```

Answer (score 2):

`--with-features=profile` doesn't seem to be valid option; `:help profile` says:

> The +profile feature is required for this. It is only included when Vim was compiled with "huge" features.

So use:

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge
```