# Vim Slowing down when creating .vimrc in $HOME

Tags: vimrc, performance

It's a couple of month that I'm using **Vim** and I'm happy with it. But working on big files *(About 2000 lines)* is really annoying.
I have some plugins and today I wanted to fix this problem. So I removed them and tested again, But oddly performance was the same!
So I removed `.vimrc` from `$HOME` and saw it works fine *(I had `syntax:on`, So not too fine)*. Tested again with `vim -u NONE` and it was great.
But when I created an **empty** `.vimrc` in `$HOME` and the slowing down problem came back!
Currently I'm using `Fedora 27` with `Vim 8.0.1427`.
I did some research but didn't find anything related to this problem. So if there is something I could do to fix this, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/182/1841) in the current state of your question we can't do a lot to help you.

Comment: one thing you can also try is `rm ~/.viminfo`. It sometimes happens that this file is very big and full of information you do not need, which may slow down starting vim.

Comment: @Naumann Did that before, Nothing changes unfortunately.

Comment: @mMontu I didn't know about that! There was 2 lines of commands in `help` that said we should add it to our custom `.vimrc`, And that fixed it, Thank you! If you could add your comment as a post, So I could mark it as answer.

Comment: Glad the issue is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in version 8 Vim started loading some default configuration when no `vimrc` is found - [`:help defaults.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults%2evim). So you could try loading those defaults in your `vimrc` (as explained on that help entry), and if it solves the problem you can comment it until you find the setting that you are missing.